# Oracle Rightnow Unable to connect to remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sockets

I am using Oracle Right now CRM. while opening the cloud application users are getting the error messages quite often, not all the time. first we thought it was because of the bandwidth usage so we tried allocation 1:1, 10 MBPS leased line for it. but still the same error is throwing.
http://textuploader.com/kyt2

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind a firewall? The RightNow app requires that quite a few hosts be opened up to outgoing traffic. The list of hosts can be found in the RightNow Environmental Configuration Guides (https://cx.rightnow.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2364/kw/Environmental%20configuration%20guide).

Find your CX version and check to make sure that outgoing traffic is open to all required hosts including:

- *.custhelp.com
- *.rightnowtech.com
- *.rightnow.com
- *.rnttraining.com
- *.livelook.com and *.livelook.net (for co-browse functionality)
- *.birst.com (for Enterprise Analytics functionality)
- *.hivelive.com (for Oracle RightNow Social functionality)
- *.rnengage.com

The guides contain other notes around network requirements that my be helpful.